# Finding a bijective function from integer to words

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory, number-systems

I need to find a function to enumerate the ordered list of sequential words based on a charset. Let me give you an example.

If the charset is "abc", the function to be found "f" should compute the following:

```
f(0) =    a
f(1) =    b
f(2) =    c
f(3) =   aa
f(4) =   ab
f(5) =   ac
f(6) =   ba
f(7) =   bb
f(8) =   bb
f(9) =   ca
f(10) =  cb
f(11) =  cc
f(12) = aaa
...
```

It is important to note that "aaa" is different from "aa" or "aaaa". This is why I found it difficult to represent abc as a number system to the base 3.

I am looking for an explicit definition of f(n) to compute f for an arbitrary n without enumerating recursively.

Comment: Looks to me that you've already precisely defined the function you want. What more do you need/want? (You might want to shift the table down a step to make room for the empty word, though).

Comment: I am looking for an explicit definition of f(n) to compute f for an arbitrary n without enumerating recursively. I#ve updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is a version of [bijective numeration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration). In particular, your $f(n)$ is the ($n+1$)th word in the [shortlex ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order) of all words on the given alphabet. (The $n+1$ is due to your omission of the empty word.) Here's an implementation (in [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)), which is essentially the algorithm given on the page at the first link above, adapted to use an arbitrary $k$-character alphabet rather than the usual digits {1, 2, ..., $k$}:

```
def number_to_word(n, alphabet):
    """
    return the nth word (n >= 0) 
    in the shortlex ordering of words on the given alphabet string
    """
    k = len(alphabet)
    word = ''
    while n != 0:
        q = ceil(n/k) - 1
        a = n - q*k
        word = alphabet[a-1] + word
        n = q
    return word
```

Here's an implementation of the inverse of that function:

```
def word_to_number(w, alphabet):
    """
    return the number n such that w is the nth word
    in the shortlex ordering of words on the given alphabet string 
    """
    k = len(alphabet)
    n = q = 0
    for c in w[::-1]:
        p = alphabet.index(c) + 1
        n = n + p*(k^q)
        q = q + 1
    return n
```

For example

```
for n in [0..15]:
    s = number_to_word(n+1,'abc')
    t = word_to_number(s,'abc')-1
    print '%d --> %s --> %d'%(n,s,t)
```

produces

```
0 --> a --> 0
1 --> b --> 1
2 --> c --> 2
3 --> aa --> 3
4 --> ab --> 4
5 --> ac --> 5
6 --> ba --> 6
7 --> bb --> 7
8 --> bc --> 8
9 --> ca --> 9
10 --> cb --> 10
11 --> cc --> 11
12 --> aaa --> 12
13 --> aab --> 13
14 --> aac --> 14
15 --> aba --> 15
```

Comment: THanks, that does the job. Is there a reverse function?

Comment: @Heinrich - I've renamed the function `n_to_word`, and added an implementation of the inverse function `word_to_n`.

Comment: Just awesome ... !

Answer (score 5):

If the alphabet contains $\sigma\ge 2$ symbols, then the word consisting of $n$ `a`s has $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sigma^i = \frac{\sigma^n-1}{\sigma-1}-1$ words in front of it. Therefore you have $f(\frac{\sigma^n-1}{\sigma-1}-1)={\tt a}^n$. (The minus one is because you don't encode the empty word).

For a word with letters other than `a`, interpret it as a numeral in base $\sigma$ to find the distance from the pure `a` word of the same length, and add it to the index.